# Javascript onclick event call to a webservice

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

Is it possible to call the below script on button click?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mypaga.com/paga-web/epay/ePay-button.paga?k=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&e=false"> </script>
```

I want to use a custom button.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logic in script but basically yes you can. See example code below. Then you have to add click event to your button with this function.

```
 function addscript() {
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   script = document.createElement('script');
   script.id = 'uploadScript';
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = "upload.js";
   head.appendChild(script);
 }
```

Comment: <form action="post" action="">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addscript() {
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   script = document.createElement('script');
   script.id = 'uploadScript';
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = "paga.js";
   head.appendChild(script);
 }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="addscript()">Try it</button>

Comment: I downloaded and saved the script as paga.js. It is not working.

Comment: As can I see script is added to page after button click. Probably script has logic on same event. You have to find this and use after script is added. But is possibile that the logic is secure and hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using the [Paga](https://www.mypaga.com/paga-web/customer) Service api. If you plan on submitting with your custom button, then after the script is loaded, you need to trigger `$('#__paga_btn').click()` which is can be found from  Using the chrome dev tools to inspect element and get the id of the link. `#__paga_btn`,  NB, the script is required to be loaded after the form element. Something like this would suffice for your case

```
function addscript() {
   var head = document.getElementsByClassName("pagalink")[0];
   script = document.createElement('script');
   script.id = 'uploadScript';
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = "https://www.mypaga.com/paga-web/epay/ePay-button.paga?k=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&e=false&layout=V";
   head.appendChild(script); //Figure out a way to detect when script has loaded.
   $('#__paga_btn').click(); // needs to be called after the script as loaded to submit the form.

 }
```

the `pagalink` node need to be placed below the form element on the page. Since that is where you would actually put the script. The script isn't really customizable since it modifies the dom on load.